# How to see the user’s RD session?

Tags: remote-desktop-services, windows-server-2019

How can I as an administrator perform “shadowing” of a user in a Remote Desktop Services environment?

My scenario is the following:

The user will log on to the RDS system and get a remote desktop session on one out of several Session Hosts.

By knowing their user name I would like to have the ability to request “shadowing” so that I can see their session and assist them with support when they run in to trouble. Ideally, the user would receive a prompt where they can choose to either approve or request the shadow request.

Is it possible to do this without third-party software? Either via GUI or PowerShell.

I know that there exist software such as [Galinette cendrée](https://sourceforge.net/projects/galinettecendree/) that can aid with this functionality, but I prefer to do it without installing any third-party tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps I'm not understanding what you're asking, but you can do this from your RDS collection in Server Manager.

[image]

[image]